# Magento 2 : Apply filter layered navigation in REST API

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter

In frontend side, layer filter apply because of this below code. But, how can i use this below line into rest api as well? Is it possible to get **$this->getRequest()** object into rest api?

Below code source file :

> **vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/Block/Navigation.php**

```
foreach ($this->filterList->getFilters($this->_catalogLayer) as $filter) {
            $filter->apply($this->getRequest());
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $categoryId = 7;

  $resource = ObjectManager::getInstance()- 
     >get(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::class);
  $connection = $resource->getConnection();

  $select = $connection->select()->from(['ea' => $connection- 
  >getTableName('eav_attribute')], 'ea.attribute_id')
  ->join(['eea' => $connection->getTableName('eav_entity_attribute')], 
 'ea.attribute_id = eea.attribute_id')
 ->join(['cea' => $connection->getTableName('catalog_eav_attribute')], 
 'ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id')
 ->join(['cpe' => $connection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity')], 
 'eea.attribute_set_id = cpe.attribute_set_id')
 ->join(['ccp' => $connection->getTableName('catalog_category_product')], 
 'cpe.entity_id = ccp.product_id')
   ->where('cea.is_filterable = ?', 1)
   ->where('ccp.category_id = ?', $categoryId)
   ->group('ea.attribute_id');


   foreach ($select as $data) {
     return $data;
   }
```